# I deleted python from my ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python-2.7

I remove python with this command `sudo apt autoremove python`

right now, i cant enter to my pc.

my ubuntu ask me, login and password but i cant enter, i dont see my files

i've made this solutions:  [Login fail after removing Python](https://askubuntu.com/questions/547278/login-fail-after-removing-python)

but dont work for me!!!

can i install only python? i dont want reinstall all my s.o

Comment: Have you tried switching to a text console (Ctrl + Alt + F3 to F6) and reinstall it from there?

Comment: @KlausD. i dont want reintall my SO

Comment: @KlausD. its possible dont reinstall my SO ?

Comment: I was talking about Python: `sudo apt-get install python`.